# Log4j re-initializes itself in the middle of the program

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Log4j re-initializes itself in the middle of the program

Hi, I'm observing an odd behaviour where log4j
appears to re-initialize itself after I load a class via 
reflection call, completely unrelated to it. It then stops 
printing while run from the console. Inside Eclipse it's fine.

Looks like a groundhog day:)

Thanks

The `-Dlog4j.debug` is turned on. At the very beginning:

```
log4j: Using URL [file:log4j.properties] ...
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/log4j.properties
log4j: Hierarchy threshold set to [ALL].
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[,console,file].
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
```

Then again, in the middle of the program:

```
log4j: Hierarchy threshold set to [ALL].
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[,console,file].
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "console".
```

`log4j.properties` is simple:

```
log4j.threshold=ALL
log4j.rootLogger=,console,file

#define standard out appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%t] %-5p %c{1}[%L]: %m%n

#define 1st file appender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/out.log
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%t] %-5p %c{1} : %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the class (or its dependency) that you are loading itself does use log4j and calls log4j initialization in its `static` initialization blocks. You can probably put a breakpoint somewhere to find out who exactly is re-initializing log4j.